# How to allow foreign keys to be saved in database as null using Entity Framework with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have three tables in my database: `Superdealer`, `subdealer` and `commission`

- Id in Superdealer: `SuperdealerId`
- Id in subdealer : `subdealerId`
- Id in commission: `commissionId`. It has two foreign keys `SuperdealerId` and `subdealerId`

There is a dropdown list which let me choose whether to assign commission to a subdealer or a superdealer itself. If I choose sub dealer value must be assigned to subdealerid and superdealerid should be null. And if I select superdealer it should be assigned a value and subdealerid should be null.

I have tried the following code but this code doesn't belong to my problem.

```
 modelBuilder .Entity<Commission>()
                    .HasOptional<SuperDealer>(u => u.SuperDealer)
                    .WithOptionalPrincipal();
 modelBuilder .Entity<Commission>()
                    .HasOptional<SubDealer>(u => u.SubDealer)
                    .WithOptionalPrincipal();

public class Commission
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CommissionId { get; set; }


    //[Display(Name ="Selected Dealer Name")]
    //public string DealerName { get; set; }
    [Range(0, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid 
    commission")]
    [Display(Name = "Commission Percentage")]
    public double CommissionPercentage { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Commission Start Date")]
    public DateTime CommissionStart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Commission")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number")]
    public int firstCommissionPart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Second Commission")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number")]
    public Nullable<int> secondCommissionPart { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Third Commission")]
    [Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid number")]
    public Nullable<int> thirdCommissionPart { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SubDealerId")]
    public SubDealer SubDealer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Select Sub dealer")]
    public int? SubDealerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("SuperDealerId")]
    public SuperDealer SuperDealer { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Select Super dealer")]
    public int? SuperDealerId { get; set; }

 }
```

This is the code of creating commission to the dealers

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "CommissionId,CommissionPercentage,CommissionStart,firstCommissionPart,secondCommissionPart,thirdCommissionPart,SubDealerId,SuperDealerId")] Commission commission, FormCollection fc)
{
        //var superdealer = Request.Form["SuperDealerId"];
        //var subdealer = Request.Form["SubDealerId"];
        int superdealer = int.Parse(fc["SuperDealerId"]);
        int subdealer = int.Parse(fc["SubDealerId"]);


        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (superdealer > 0 && subdealer > 0)
            {
                commission.SubDealerId = subdealer;
            }
            else if (superdealer > 0)
            {
                commission.SuperDealerId = superdealer;
            }
            db.Commissions.Add(commission);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        List<SelectListItem> plans = new List<SelectListItem>();

        plans.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "QM Plan", Value = "1", Selected = true });

        plans.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Customized Plan", Value = "2" });
        ViewBag.Plans = plans;
        ViewBag.SubDealerId = new SelectList(db.SubDealers, "SubDealer_No", "Name", commission.SubDealerId);
        ViewBag.SuperDealerId = new SelectList(db.SuperDealers, "SuperDealer_No", "Name", commission.SuperDealerId);
        return View(commission);
}
```

What I want is

1. There can be many subdealers under a super dealer. There is a drop down list which let me choose whether to assign commission to a subdealer or a superdealer itself. If i choose sub dealer value must be assigned to subdealerid and superdealerid should be null. and if i select superdealer it should be assigned a value and subdealerid should be null.

When I click, I get the following error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SM23p.jpg

Comment: How concrete is the structure?  Could you perhaps change `Commission` to have a CommissionID, DealerID and DealerType?  Then, you add whichever ID (Subdealer or Superdealer) to the commission and indicate the type.